# Turning a Magento website into an online catalouge without Prices and a shopping basket

Tags: magento, e-commerce

Hey im just looking for some advice, my project is to create a website on magento without the price option. This means no shopping basket either but just the option for users to view all the products without having the option to buy it online. Its important that i still keep the feature of selling online for the future but if it was possible to just disable it all.

Id love for some insight onto what people think the best option is for me to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should do three things:

- Remove all inclusions for the prices from your theme (just comment them out)
- Remove the button in the addtocart.phtml files
- Disable onepage checkout via the backend

Comment: okay so just manually go through and comment all inclusions for price out? thanks for the quick reply anyone got additonal advice?